# Can I use "linked list" when creating examples in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

Can I use linkedlist when I create Instances?

Example:

I have `Main` class and a class `Employee`.

**Main.class:**

```
 Employee a1 = new Employee();
```

When we create Instances, usually do the code like this.

But I'm wondering if there's any way to create an instance using linked list.

Like this:

```
LinkedList<String> alist = new LinkedList<String>();  
Employee alist(index) = new Employee();
```

Comment: Yes, a linked list (or any other Java collection) can hold a collection of `Employee` objects.  Check out the Oracle trail on collections.

Comment: Be aware that in almost all cases in Java, using `ArrayList` makes more sense than using `LinkedList`. `ArrayList` uses less memory and is generally faster. See also [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just instantiate the element when adding it to the list

```
alist.add(new employee());
```

Given your code, you should also change your declaration. So the result would be:

```
LinkedList<Employee> alist = new LinkedList<>();
 alist.add(new Employee());
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please make sure to mark the answer as correct if you think it is ^^

Comment: You cannot add an instance of `Employee` to any `List<String>`...

Comment: @thrillingchase Please be specific: in what way doesn't it work? The problem is probably that you are creating a `LinkedList<String>`, which can't contain an `Employee`...

Comment: You declared the LinkedList as a container of <Strings>. Employee is probably not a string, so either add strings to it, or change <String> to <Employee>.

Comment: Check the addition I did on the answer. You need to make the LinkedList of Employee, not of String.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a `List<String>`, which cannot hold instances of `Employee`, but maybe their names...

It seems like you want something like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
// maybe set some attributes (the next line is a guess due to a lack of information)
employee.setName("E. M. Ployee");

// create a list of employees
List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>();
// and add the employee
employees.add(employee);
```

If you have a `List<String>` and a `class Employee` that looks similar to this one

```
class Employee {

    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

then you can create an instance of `Employee` for each name in the list of names:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a list of names (String)
    List<String> names = new LinkedList<>();
    names.add("E. M. Ployee");
    names.add("U. R. Fired");
    // create a list of employees (Employee)
    List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>();
    // go through the names and create an Employee for each one
    names.forEach(name -> employees.add(new Employee(name)));
    // then print the names from the employee objects that are in the list of employees
    employees.forEach(employee -> System.out.println(employee.getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>();

employees.add(new Employee(..., ..., ...));

Employee empMarta = new Employee("Marta", "Green", 24);

employees.add(empMarta);
```

1. Maybe it's better to use some SET interface implementation (Set has unique list of elements)?
2. For Employee class you should override equals() and hashCode() methods;
3. And the main thing: if you decide to use List, then you should answer to the question "What is the most frequent operation You plan to perform (add, search, delete)?". Based on answer you should choose between ArrayList and LinkedList.